# Unable to ignore path while migrating svn to git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I am looking foward to migrate my code from SVN to Git using svn2git.

Below is my SVN path

```
 ${SVN_PATH}/branches
 ${SVN_PATH}/tags
 ${SVN_PATH}/trunk/EAR/EARjar1
 ${SVN_PATH}/trunk/EAR/EARjar1
 ${SVN_PATH}/trunk/EJS/EJSjar1
 ${SVN_PATH}/trunk/EJS/EJSjar1
```

I am looking to migrate only EJSjar1 and EJSjar2. But Unfortunately I m not able to ignore SVN paths for EARjar.

```
svn2git SVN_PATH --no-minimize-url --trunk trunk --tags tags --nobranches --authors authors.txt --exclude '*EAR*' --verbose

Running command: git config --local --get user.name
Running command: git config --local svn.authorsfile authors.txt
Running command: git svn fetch '--ignore-paths=^(?:trunk[/]|tags[/][^/]+[/]) ('tags[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
command failed:
git svn fetch '--ignore-paths=^(?:trunk[/]|tags[/][^/]+[/])(?:*EAR*)'
```

I have tried various combination in --exclude like

```
 '.*EAR.*' 
 '*EAR*'
```

But still the error persists. Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong.

Thanks !